# Highlight cells that are duplicates that are no adjacent

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm looking for conditional formatting that will highlight cells that are duplicates of a group of adjacent cells. In the example photo I'd like the PO column cells to only highlight themselves if the same PO number is used again but NOT adjacent to the rest.

[image: Example]

Comment: This would work most of the time, but would not if I had the same company and PO# again. In this example ACME and 1001 on the list further down. or in other words if it didn't say Callahan Auto Parts and instead said Acme, the CF would not highlight the duplicate PO#'s

Comment: I had thought about something that would count cells between, and including, the 1st use of a PO# and last use of it, and if the countif of that PO# was not the same count, then the CF would kick in.

Comment: Yes, I agree that would be quite difficult in the CF field, but I wanted to share my idea incase you or someone else could take inspiration from it.